# Error when setting ComboBox.Sorted property to true

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

It is a basic `ComboBox` with the following code:

```
private void hotel_Selection()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM HOTEL WHERE HOTEL_CITY = @CITY", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CITY", citiesID);
    SqlDataReader dr1;
    dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt1.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
    dt1.Load(dr1);
    hotelCbox.ValueMember = "ID";
    hotelCbox.DisplayMember = "NAME";
    hotelCbox.DataSource = dt1;
    hotelCbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    con.Close();
}
```

The problem arises when I try to get the `ComboBox` to be sorted from A-Z. If I don't set the sorted property to true it works, but as soon as I try to set the property to true it gives me the error for the `System.Data.DataRowView` and it is slowly driving me crazy.Any idea what am I doing wrong, perhaps as it is sql or am I missing something along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in documentations for [`Sorted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) property:

> Attempting to set the `Sorted` property on a data-bound control raises
>   an ArgumentException. You must sort the data using the underlying data
>   model.

To solve the problem you can sort the `DataTable` by assigning a sort expression to the [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) property of its `DefaultView`.

The value of property can be the column name followed by `ASC`  for ascending sort or `DESC` for descending sort. Columns are sorted ascending by default. You can apply sort to multiple columns by separating sort expressions by comma.

```
dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "Name";
```

You also can sort your query by adding an [`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM HOTEL WHERE HOTEL_CITY = @CITY ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I skipped the ArgumentException entirely, thank you a lot!